# sum even numbers in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

In this code, I need create a function which will sum even numbers in my BST.  I don't know how to pass all nodes of my tree.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node *newNode(int item) {
struct node *temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key) {
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    return node;
}

void main(void)
{
    struct node *root = NULL;
    int data[]={3,1,2,6,4,7,8}, n, i;
    n=sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        root=insert(root,data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Write a recursive function that iterates through all the elements in the tree. It checks each element to see if it's even, and then adds it to the variable holding the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Sorry, have no C-compiler at hand.

```
int sum(struct node *root) {
   if (root == NULL) {
     return 0;
   }
   int value = 0;
   if (root->key % 2 == 0) {
      value = root->key;
   }
   return value + sum(root->left) + sum(root->right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of the different search, BFS or DFS, for search in every node of the tree. Also in every moment you should save the actual sum of even numbers. The comparison should be like

```
if(node->key % 2 == 0){
    final += node->key;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i have this ... but its wrong because the result is zero

`void sum(struct node *root)
{
    int sum=0;
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        if(root->key % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum+root->key;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of even numbers is %d", sum);
}`